# how to display a popup form after checking a checkbox in extjs

Tags: extjs

does anyone know how to create a simple ExtJS 'pop-up form', meaning the user checks a checkbox(the grid has several checkboxes,each pops a different form fields) on a grid, a pop-up appears on the screen to ask for some input from the user,then that information is displayed on a grid.

Answer (score 2):

like so

```
{
    boxLabel  : 'Anchovies',
    name      : 'topping',
    inputValue: '1',
    id        : 'checkbox1',
    listeners: {
        change: function(cb, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
            if(newValue === true)
                Ext.Msg.alert('Notify', newValue);
        }
    }
}
```